# swift: gray color in bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have `NavigationViewController` with white navigation bar color. When I go from `firstViewController` to `secondViewController` I see gray color in my navigation bar. I want to remove this gray color. How to fix it?

`firstViewController`:

[image]

go to `secondViewController`:

[image]

`secondViewController`:

[image]

How to remove this:

[image]

my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
}
```

Comment: @Carpsen90 Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you need to set isTranslucent property to true

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: Doesn't works. Works if `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` but it is not fits.

Comment: try the other solution by @kishu

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.